# How to serialize a query array result and store in the database table

Tags: php, sql, serialization

How do I serialize this result and store it in the database;

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ingredientID] => 2
        [code] => Bf
        [description] => 1st Class Flour
        [volume] => 8268
        [price] => 750
        [amount_gram] => 0.02980
        [status] => Inactive
        [uom_id] => 1
        [flour] => Yes
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ingredientID] => 3
        [code] => Sf
        [description] => 3rd Class Flour
        [volume] => 18490
        [price] => 635
        [amount_gram] => 0.02540
        [status] => Inactive
        [uom_id] => 5
        [flour] => Yes
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
................
```

Comment: cant you do serialize($yourObject); and store in database...?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: May I note that storing entire objects in serialized form usually exposes a design flaw rather than a functional requirement?

What's the reason you wanna do this?

Answer (score 3):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

```
$i = serialize($var2serialized);
```

`$i` will contain the serialized form of the array.

You would then need to add `$i` as part of your database query to store.

Comment: Please look at the formatting guide when you create your answer. Indent code with four spaces to begin block highlighting and surround inline code with ` (above tab key) to highlight them too.